ReactNative - Cmake changes "/" to "\" and then he doesent recognise the path
I have a react native project where i specified an ndk through local.properties with ndk.dir=C:/Users/.../Android/Sdk/ndk/14.1.3816874
When i try to assembleRelease in a Cmake file in expo-modules-core he changes the every "/" to "\" and then pops out this error :
when parsing string

      C:\Users\...\Android\Sdk\ndk\14.1.3816874

    Invalid character escape '\U'.

because he reads the \Users.
I've tried changing from "/" to "\\", moving the ndk folder but the problem is that when i compile he modify the Cmake with the wrong "\".
if anyone experinced this...
